# TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline - the same thread or context?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronizationcontext

[MSDN documentation of TryExecuteTaskInline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.tryexecutetaskinline(v=vs.110).aspx) states that:

> A class derived from TaskScheduler implements this function to support
>   inline execution of a task on a thread that initiates a wait on that
>   task object.

However, if you look in the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskScheduler.cs), the implementation of `TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline`:

```
protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
{
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current == m_synchronizationContext)
    {
        return TryExecuteTask(task);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

only checks if the current synchronization context is the same as one captured during the instantiation (see the `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` constructor in the same source file). Multiple threads can share one synchronization context, so it doesn't necessarily mean the same thread.

So it's either than I don't actually understand what the documentation says, or it's wrong. Could anyone explain that?

I just can't see how this implementation 'supports inline execution of a task on a thread that initiates a wait on that task object.', as required by documentation of that method. It just calls TryExecuteTask, which calls task's ExecuteEntry (you can just click on the method name to jump to its source).

Comment: That code doesn't execute the task, you're looking at the wrong spot. The only thing this says is that you can only execute the task on the same thread if the synchronization context is the same. How it is queued is a different topic.

Comment: What are you confused about? Some thread initiates a wait on that task object and `TryExecuteTaskInline` check if that (current for `TryExecuteTaskInline`) thread satisfy constraints, required by this particular `TaskScheduler`, and if yes it try to execute task on current thread. `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` requires particular context, not particular thread. You can write your own `TaskScheduler`, which would have its own different requirements.

Comment: @Voo `TryExecuteTask` is actually execute task on current thread, if some other thread not yet started it.

Comment: @PetserAl Yes, my point is that since the shown code doesn't actually execute the task, it's the wrong code to check. Although obviously from the naming it's clear that `TryExecuteTask` won't queue the task for another thread - still for posterity you'd have to check there.

Comment: @Voo well, okay, I understand that, but I just can't see how this implementation 'supports inline execution of a task **on a thread that initiates a wait on that task object**.', as required by documentation of that method. It just calls `TryExecuteTask`, which calls task's `ExecuteEntry` (you can just click on the method name to jump to its source).

Comment: What don't you understand? By this implementation (assuming that `TryExecuteTask` just executes the task on the current thread), if the waiting thread has the same synchronization context as the task that should be executed it can be run on that waiting thread. Clearly some other implementation could have further limitations, but this one seems pretty straight foward.

Comment: @Voo  
I think I got it - 'supports inline execution of a task on a thread that initiates a wait on that task object' doesn't mean it should **ensure** that the inline execution happens on the same thread that initiated a wait on that task object?

Comment: That's what the *Try* implies no?

Comment: @Voo maybe I should ask what is inline execution - does it require that the task is executed on the same thread that initiated wait on this task? I can only see that it runs it on **current** thread, no idea if it's the same thread that called wait.

Comment: That's the whole point of that feature. If a task calls Wait on a task, you check to see if the task isn't already running and whether the task's synchronization context allows it to be executed on that particular thread. It's an optimisation nothing more.

Comment: @Voo but `TryExecuteTaskInline` **doesn't** check if the task will execute on the same thread that called wait on this task. Or maybe it does, then show me where it is verified. It can't be checked by only looking at synchronization context, because you can have many threads using the same synchronization context.

Comment: Yes, neither does string.IsEmpty() - you're not magically going to jump from one thread to another just by calling a method.